# Error in executing a simple JPA Project with Spring

Tags: java, spring-data

I tried to execute a simple JPA Spring program, but it failed with error given below.

```
Error creating bean with name 'productService': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRepositori'; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'productRepositori':
Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7d9f158f' of 
type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager';

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7d9f158f':
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

I ran a test on another computer and it was successful with this project, but on my computer it was unsuccessful, I thought it was a conflict with JDK, So I installed the version that ran on the other machine, but still no luck.
I hope it will run successfully

**ProductRepositori interface**

```
package com.demo.repositories;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.demo.entities.Product;
@Repository("productRepositori") 
public interface ProductRepositori extends CrudRepository < Product, Integer > {

}
```

**ProductService interface**

```
package com.demo.services;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.demo.entities.Product;
@Service 
public interface ProductService {
 public Iterable < Product > findAll();
}
```

Comment: hi 
Could you please share your code productRepositori,productService.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Are you using external **entityManager**? What is your configuration? Show me the code...

Comment: package com.demo.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.demo.entities.Product;


@Repository("productRepositori")
public interface ProductRepositori extends CrudRepository<Product,Integer> {

}

Comment: Hi there, Welcome to SO. You must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please add the code with proper formatting in the question itself.

Comment: do you have any ProductService implementation class...

Comment: yes i have ProductService Implement

Comment: When you ask about an exception, always post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: u r using java configuration or spring @Autowiring